# VCS XMRE error on continuous assignment from some signal in a conditionally generated instance

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have some Verilog code that looks something like this

```
module top_tb
  genUnit genUnit1;
  spyUnit spyUnit1;
endmodule

module unitX(...)
  logic some_signal;
endmodule

module genUnit
  unitX unit1(….);
  **generate
  if(myparam==2) begin : generate_block_2
    unitX unit2(….);
  end
  endgenerate**
endmodule

module spyUnit
  output logic spy1;
  output logic spy2;
  assign spy1 = genUnit1.unit1.some_signal;
  **generate
  if(myparam==2) begin : assign_spy_2
    assign spy2 = genUnit1.unit2.some_signal;
  end
  endgenerate**
endmodule
```

VCS Error-[XMRE] Cross-module reference resolution error with this code on assignment to spy2 (spy1 assignment is fine).  spy2 only needs to be assigned when mypram is 2, but when parsing parameter values are not defined yet, so assign statement is parsed regardless of final parameter value.  Since existence of hierarchy is dependent of parameter value I run into this issue.

So how do I do this type of parameter dependent assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Generate statements add a layer to the hierarchical name. Therefore, 
`top_tb.genUnit1.generate_block_2.unit2.some_signal` should be the path.